# What are the possible ways the following expression is actually evaluated?

Tags: java, boolean, short-circuit-evaluation

**Note - Assume the code is in JAVA**

Suppose I have a function -

```
public boolean Helper(){
boolean a = ...;
boolean b = ...;
boolean c = ...;
boolean d = ...;
return a || b && c || d;
}
```

I want to understand what are the possible ways in which the expression is actually evaluated. I am not talking about the logic table where we fill up ones and zeroes.
For example - To my understanding, if a is true, it won't matter what values the rest of the variables hold.( As there will be short circuit evaluation)
Can someone please help me in listing down all such conclusions? This boolean expression is very confusing to me

Comment: Rewrite the expression with parenthesis representing the actual evaluation logic (due to precedence of operators), then apply the short circuit rules (like `true || x` won't evaluate `x`). It should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Changing this piece of code is not in my hand. I can only study it and draw conclusions

Comment: Request you to help me figure out all the possible cases

Comment: You can still analyse the code by placing the parentheses @GaëlJ suggested for yourself. That's just an easier way to visualise what would happen anyway (try to google "precendence of operators" -- that'll help you a lot).

Comment: @xerx593 - 'and' takes precedence over 'or', in Java and in most other programming languages, as well as propositional logic.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know is three things:

1. Precedence rules. That is evaluated either as `(a || b) && (c || d)`, or as `a || (b && c) || d` or as `((a || b) && c) || d`. A simple matter of searching the web for 'java operators precedence' will get you your answer.
2. Awareness that in java, the doubled up versions of the or and and operator (`||` and `&&`, being used here) 'short circuit'. `a && b` will not eval b if `a` is false, as the result is already known.
3. basic logic tables.

All this stuff is trivially found. I think the homework exercise partly involves you actually looking all this up :)